# The dual space of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Difficulties understanding the proof.

Tags: functional-analysis

The proof I have is given as

[image]

However I don't follow the part where equality is achieved in the Cauchy inequality. Can someone help me with the details, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $x = (\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$, from the inequality
$$
|f(x)| \leq \|x\|\left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
it should be clear that
$$
\|f\| \leq \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Suppose strict inequality holds, i.e.
$$
\|f\| = A < \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Then for all nonzero $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
|f(x)| \leq A\|x\| < \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}\|x\|.
$$
But note that with $x = (\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_k)$, we have
$$
|f(x)| = \left|\sum \gamma_k^2\right| = \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2} = \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}\|x\| > A\|x\|,
$$
that is,
$$
|f(x)| > A\|x\|,
$$
which contradicts the definition of $A$. Therefore we conclude that
$$
\|f\| = \left(\sum \gamma_k^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$